# onPause difference between screen lock and incoming call

Tags: android, onresume

I'm developing an audio application. It plays sounds in the background and I want it to turn off when an incoming call happens but not when the screen locks.
My first chance was to call player.stop() on onPause as I thought it will do the trick when incoming or other applications will run on top. 
But I found that screen lock calls also this onPause event.

Is there any chance to get the cause of that calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this article has what you are looking for:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Has some snippets of code explaining how to handle if the screen turns off etc.

Hope that helps some!

Comment: Hi Luke, thank you for your answer. I was reading but it didn't work for my purposes as it calls the broadcast AFTER the onPause so I couldn't get the correct action in onPause.
What I did was to ignore the onPause and implements an android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE listener so just in case I get it I stop the sound, otherwise I leave the sound playing.
Thank you very much

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Glad you got it all sorted!