# get onPause reason android

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any way to get the **onPause()** reason or the event that execute make the activity in pause ?

Example

```
@Override
public void onPause() {

    Log.d(TAG, ">> onPause()");

    if(onPauseReason() == SCREEN_OFF)
    {
       //Do something
    }
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "<< onPause()");
}
```

**onPauseReason()** is the function that gives the reason of the onPause.

Comment: Android doesn't have anything like this. What do you need this for? If it's just for the screen turning off, there are ways to be notified when that happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087426/onpause-difference-between-screen-lock-and-incoming-call

Comment: and what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I don't know if I understood what you mean, do you want to know why android calls onPause method in your application??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110544/android-detect-what-caused-the-onpause

Comment: Yes I want the activity do not go to the onPause status after SCREEn_OFF event.

Comment: Is there any way to disable onPause() when screen is off ??